# jquery selector text box with Ul html

Tags: jquery

What is the meaning of jquery selector given below ?

Will it fetch multiple selectors?

```
$("input:text", "#ulCollateralLangVarient> li")
```

Note: `ulCollateralLangVarient` is the id of unordered html list

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is used to find the first selector *within* the second selector. It's equivalent to using `find()`:

```
$("#ulCollateralLangVarient > li").find("input:text");
```

From your comment on the other answer:

> Are these the same thing?
>   `$("input:text", "#ulCollateralLangVarient> li")`
>   `$("input:text, #ulCollateralLangVarient> li")`

No, they're not the same. The first one is as described above, whereas the second is looking for `input:text` **or** `#ulCollateralLangVarient > li`.

Comment: Thank you Rory. Much appreciated !!
For below format, could you please send me any reference links (tutorial).

$("input:text", "#ulCollateralLangVarient> li")
or
$("#input 1", "#input 2")

I could not find on internet :(

Answer (score -1):

selector will just select your all elements that are releated to that tag name that you'll pass in(). And it will store all them in array.You can access them by passing index number or by firstchid methhod.

Comment: Thank you Zia.. my question.. $("input:text", "#ulCollateralLangVarient> li") or $("input:text, #ulCollateralLangVarient> li") are the same thing. ??

Comment: @ZiaUddin it's not a syntax error. Both are valid but do different things

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan have you tried dear? i marked them syntax error because they are not showing the result that he wants .

Comment: Just because it doesn't perform as intended doesn't make it a syntax error. Also just FYI, 'dear' is a very demeaning term in this context.

Comment: Better yet, use the actual jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score -1):

if you want to select all input elements then try this it'll help you.
`$("h1,div,p")` selects all `<h1>`, `<div>` and `<p>` elements.